# Use case of Avro in Hadoop applications

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, avro

I am new to hadoop and mapreduce framework. I was going through some of the serialization formats . One of them is Avro. which seems to be very efficient and compact format.

Now lets say I have some text data in HDFS , normally I write the mapreduce job to read that data and generate the output  (or I can run hive queries ) .

I wanted to know when will i use this in my custom applications 
(mapreduce jobs or hive ) ? From which point onwards (data ingestion/processing) in real world  applications , avro will come into picture.

Answer (score 0):

Avro was created by Doug Cutting.  It is an efficient way to store data in a binary format.  This is similar to a sequenceFile in hadoop.  It supports compressing blocks.  Each file contains a json schema.  This schema can evolve and be backwards compatible.  Hive, impala, and other products all like this format.  This along with performance increases make it popular.  Parquet files are also becoming popular.

Comment: Thanks invoketheshell. This is general understanding of AVRO which you have rightly explained .  However I was expecting some explaination in the way avro is typically used in production applications